# Persist Symfony upgrade in Docker container

Tags: php, docker, symfony

I have a PHP-based Docker container with Composer and Symfony installed inside of it. But each time I start that container, a message from Symfony appears, proposing to download & install the last version (and to activate TLS), which I do (for both). So I think the upgrade doesn't persist, how can I solve this ? (thank you in advance)

Thank you for your answers, everyone. The **docker-composer.yaml** and **php/Dockerfile** are made from a French tutorial video, slightly modified due to improvements noted in the Youtube comment section: The video is called "*Un environnement de développement Symfony 5 avec Docker et Docker-compose*" from Yoandev Co. Here is the **docker-compose.yaml** :

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:

  db:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: db_SF_tuto_2
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db-data2:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: admin
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
    networks:
      - dev2

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin_SF_tuto_2
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8090:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
    networks:
      - dev2

  maildev:
    image: maildev/maildev
    container_name: maildev_SF_tuto_2
    command: bin/maildev --web 80 --smtp 25 --hide-extensions STARTTLS
    ports:
      - "8091:80"
    restart: always
    networks:
      - dev2

  www:
    build: php
    container_name: www_SF_tuto_2
    ports:
      - "8742:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./php/vhosts:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ./:/var/www
    restart: always
    networks:
        - dev2

networks:
  dev2:

volumes:
  db-data2:
```

… and **php/Dockerfile** :

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf \
\
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
       locales apt-utils git libicu-dev g++ libpng-dev libxml2-dev libzip-dev libonig-dev libxslt-dev unzip \
\
    && echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen \
    && echo "fr_FR.UTF-8 UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen \
    && locale-gen \
\
    && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- \
    && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer \
\
    &&  curl -sS https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer | bash \
    &&  mv /root/.symfony/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin \
\
    && docker-php-ext-configure \
           intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
           pdo_mysql gd opcache intl zip calendar xsl \
\
    && pecl install apcu && docker-php-ext-enable apcu

WORKDIR /var/www/
```

Comment: Could you let us know the docker command or the contents of your docker compose file please

Comment: Usually you'd make updates like this in your image's Dockerfile.  As you've noticed, any changes you make in a running container will be lost as soon as the container exits.

Comment: Sounds like you need a volume defined to persist data.  As indicated, please provide the yml.

Comment: What's your use case? Do you _really_ need `symfony-cli` installed in the container? I'm guessing is to run the server, and that would be ok (I guess) for a development image, as it's not recommended for production use. Any of [these solutions](https://github.com/symfony/cli/issues/154) work for you?

Comment: Post edited with the content of docker-compose.yaml and php/Dockerfile.

@msg My use case is just that I'm learning Symfony (and Docker), so nothing quite serious so far. I've read the topic you've mentionned, my problem is more about persisting the update that accept new updates automatically ;)

Comment: @msg How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered, container storage is temporary and any changes done in it will be discarded when the container is removed. Note that you can *stop* a running container and the changes will still be there the next time you launch it, but `docker-compose down` does remove it, so every time you boot up your symfony binary is being reloaded from the image.

If you want for the updates to persist you'll have to create a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes).

However, since your current installation directory already contains binaries from your base image I'd suggest installing to a different directory and mount that.

In your `Dockerfile`, change the installation target. Since its a new directory you need to add it to the current `$PATH` so the tools can be executed.

```
FROM php:7.4-apache

RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf \
\
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
       locales apt-utils git libicu-dev g++ libpng-dev libxml2-dev libzip-dev libonig-dev libxslt-dev unzip \
    && echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen \
    && echo "fr_FR.UTF-8 UTF-8" >> /etc/locale.gen \
    && locale-gen \
\
    && mkdir /opt/bin -p \
    && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir /opt/bin --filename composer \
    && curl -sS https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer | bash -s - --install-dir /opt/bin \
\
    && docker-php-ext-configure \
           intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
           pdo_mysql gd opcache intl zip calendar xsl \
\
    && pecl install apcu && docker-php-ext-enable apcu

ENV PATH /opt/bin:$PATH

WORKDIR /var/www/
```

Now specify where to map the volume in the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
  www:
    # ...
    volumes:
      # Specify the mount point. 
      # If you use short syntax here, a volume will be created every restart.
      - phptools:/opt/bin

volumes:
  # Declare a named volume so it can be remounted
  phptools:
```

Run `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I tried what you said but an error appears when `docker-compose build` is run: 

``#5 36.52 All settings correct for using Composer
#5 36.52 Downloading...
#5 37.38
#5 37.38 Composer (version 2.0.13) successfully installed to: /opt/bin/composer
#5 37.38 Use it: php /opt/bin/composer
#5 37.38
#5 37.38 mv: cannot stat 'composer.phar': No such file or directory
------
ERROR: Service 'www' failed to build``

I'll post the Dockerfile in the next answer

Comment: @Daemian You were moving the installed `composer.phar` to `composer`, my updated installation steps already do that, so you can remove the `mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer` and the symfony binary move too.

Comment: Here is the Dockerfile :

FROM php:7.4-apache
[...] (_see the middle lines here from the original post_)
    && locale-gen \
\
    && mkdir /opt/bin -p\
\
    && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir /opt/bin --filename composer \
    && mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer \
\
    &&  curl -sS https://get.symfony.com/cli/installer | bash -s - --install-dir /opt/bin \
    &&  mv /root/.symfony/bin/symfony /usr/local/bin \
\
    && docker-php-ext-configure \
[...] (_see original post_)

WORKDIR /var/www

ENV PATH /opt/bin:$PATH

Comment: Hum, sorry, I'm new here, I don't know how to force the text to go to a new line...

Comment: Oh, okay, thank you, I am going to try that

Comment: So, after removing the `mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer` and the symfony binary move too, doing `docker-compose up -d` doesn't fully work. All the containers but the PHP (www) one starts. The PHP one (which I called www_SF_tuto_2) keeps on restarting : `Status : Restarting (0) 30 seconds ago` (according to `docker container ps`)

Comment: @Daemian The whole stack comes up for me: `0afc8930177e   devel_www              "docker-php-entrypoi…"   6 minutes ago   Up 5 minutes   80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8742->8000/tcp, :::8742->8000/tcp      www_SF_tuto_2`. I've included my whole dockerfile. Also try checking `docker logs www_SF_tuto_2` to see if gives you any clues or run it in the foreground (without `-d` in `docker-compose up`).

Comment: Thanks a lot, everything works fine :)  Actually the problem was coming from an old command line I forgot to remove in my Dockerfile ^^